# Converting a Mercurial branch into the same repository, but different branch

Tags: mercurial

We are faced with a situation where we are maintaining two code bases in the same repository.  The folder structure looks like this:

/WebRoot/

In our default branch the /WebRoot/ is very different from the /WebRoot/ in the Stable branch.  The goal is to move /WebRoot/ from the Stable branch to /WebRoot/ in default branch.   And the current default /WebRoot/ will become /WebRootX/.  So in the end, all code will be in default and we won't have to switch back and forth between default and Stable branches when making changes in the two different code bases.

```
|      |      | 
|      |      |
|      --------
|      |      QA
|      |
-------|
|     Stable
|
```

default

I'm thinking that we have to use hg convert to move the Stable code out to a different (temp) repository.   Then rename the default WebRoot to WebRootX.  Then import the Stable /WebRoot/ folder back in.

I have done several tests and I'm not getting the desired results.  I have tried using hg convert with the branchmap ("Stable default") to get the Stable branch out to a temp repository, but that's not working.   I'm seeing code from default in there.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you require that you keep the repository history in tact? If not the easiest thing to so would just be switch to the stable branch, grab your WebRoot folder and place it somewhere, switch back to default and put the stable folder back in. It's a lazy way but by far the easiest if you're just trying to have both directories in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before trying anything below first back up your repo.

Now you can try this: in the `default` branch, rename `WebRoot` to `WebRootX`. Commit this change.

Still in the `default` branch, merge in the `stable` branch using the `internal:fail` merge tool (what git calls a merge strategy):

```
hg merge --tool internal:fail stable
```

At this point, your working copy is in a state that, if committed, Mercurial will accept as a successful merge. *But* before you commit, you want to tell Mercurial to revert the entire `WebRoot` directory structure to its state in the `stable` branch, while at the same time not reverting anything that in the `WebRootX` directory structure:

```
hg revert --all -r stable -IWebRoot* -XWebRootX*
```

At this point you should have the `WebRootX` directory structure as it was in the `default` branch, while at the same time having the `WebRoot` directory structure as it was in the `stable` branch, *and* also preserving both their histories.

I have to warn you though I just roughly tested this out in a dummy repo and I'm not sure what results you'll get in a 'real' repo.

Some ideas from [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge).

Comment: This is exactly what we needed to do.  I ran these steps and both WebRoot and WebRootX seem to be the desired result.  All revision history was retained in both folders as well.  I did need to run an "hg resolve -a -m" after the hg merge.  Other than that, the steps you gave did the trick.  Thanks for the answer!